# Display a certain image quality based on connection type

Tags: javascript, html, image, web

I'm trying to set up a site for people to view 360 images. As 360 images are big, I'm thinking of providing a lower quality picture for devices connected to Mobile Data. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Detection pretty much limited https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API

Comment: Why not show thumbnails and let the user decide how to manage their own bandwidth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thanh Trung mentioned, Network Information API is very limited. What I could think of is sending a 1 - 2 MB file to users device and see how much time it takes to download, based on that you will get idea about the connection speed. Based on that you can write your logic to pull the respective images.

However, the catch is if the user is travelling or moving then the network may fluctuate.